# simple use of sprintf fails

Tags: c, printf, stdio

If I run

```
filename="heat.dat";
prtdat(u_x_length, u_y_length, u[iz],filename);
```

it works fine. If I change the first line to

```
printf("%d",sprintf(filename,"heat.dat"));
```

the output is 8, and then my program crashes. Why??
My actual aim is to use `sprintf(filename,"heat%dof%d.dat",rank,numtasks)`.

If you need the prtdat routine, here goes:

```
void prtdat(int u_x_length, int u_y_length, float *u, char *fnam) {
int ix, iy;
FILE *fp;

fp = fopen(fnam, "w");
for (iy = 0; iy < u_y_length; iy++) 
      for (ix = 0; ix < u_x_length; ix++) 
      {
        fprintf(fp, "%6.1f", *(u+iy*u_x_length+ix));
        if (ix != u_x_length-1) 
          fprintf(fp, " ");
        else
          fprintf(fp, "\n");
      }
fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Did you allocate memory, pointed to by `filename` ?

Comment: Please show how you declare `filename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"heat.dat"` in your code is a constant string literal. It is allocated in the read-only data segment of your program. Thus, your `filename` pointer points to a read-only memory after the `filename="heat.dat";` assignment. The result is an undefined behavior. In order for your idea to work you have to have `filename` pointing to a non-constant memory of a sufficient size to store a string that you are trying to store in that memory. For example:

```
char filename[256]; /* This is the key - a non-constant memory is allocated on stack */
printf("%d",sprintf(filename,"heat.dat")); /* sprintf now does not crash */
```

Comment: You are welcome. Good Luck with your programming, I hope you enjoy it!

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
filename="heat.dat";
```

suggests that `filename` is a `[const] char *` pointer. In that case in order to do

```
sprintf(filename, "heat.dat")
```

you have to pre-allocate a writable memory buffer, which `filename` will point to and which will be sufficiently large to hold `"heat.dat"` string. What method did you use to allocate that buffer?

Comment: If `filename` were declared const, the program wouldn't compile.

Comment: @KerrekSB or at least it would emit a warning. As far as I know, most C compilers (including GCC and clang) only warn about const correctness and don't issue an error.

Comment: @H2CO3: Ah, you're right, it's only a warning in C. It's an error in C++, though :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, C++ has a much stricter type system than that of C (with all its advantages and disadvantages). :)

Comment: @H2CO3: Formal strictness of type system in C and C++ is virtually the same. Const correctness violation is an error in both languages. Loose error checking we often encounter in some C compilers is a problem of those compilers alone and their default settings, not an indication of some inherent differences between C and C++.

Comment: @AndreyT Thanks for the clarification. (I suspected this, as the C standard states that a program which was compiled but a diagnostic was generated has undefined behavior.)